# How to delete vertical lines in Rickshaw histogram?

Tags: javascript, histogram, rickshaw

Now I have 1 element in data and my histogram looks like:

[image: Rickshaw histogram]

How to delete vertical lines and delete copy of x-axis component? And how to set histogram height so rectangles was to enlarge than histogram height?

Note: code:

```
 var graph = new Rickshaw.Graph({
     element: document.querySelector("#chart"),
     renderer: 'bar',
     width: 540,
     height: 240,
     series: [{
                data: createArray(data),
                color: 'steelblue'
       }]
     });


  var x_axis = new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.X({
      graph: graph,
      tickFormat:  function(x){
          return (new Date(x)).toLocaleString();
      }
    });

  var y_axis = new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.Y({
        graph: graph,
        orientation: 'left',
        tickFormat: Rickshaw.Fixtures.Number.formatKMBT,
        element: document.getElementById('y_axis')
    });

  graph.render();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't want vertical lines remove this:

```
  var x_axis = new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.X({
      graph: graph,
      tickFormat:  function(x){
          return (new Date(x)).toLocaleString();
      }
    });
```

from your code.

follow this:http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/tutorial/introduction.html